# Speed comparison of 2 loop styles

Tags: c++, loops

I'm reading about STL algorithms and the book pointed out that algorithms like find use a while loop rather than a for loop because it is minimal, efficient, and uses one less variable. I decided to do some testing and the results didn't really match up.

The forfind consistently performed better than the whilefind. At first I simply tested by pushing 10000 ints back into a vector, and then using find to get a single value from it and return it to the iterator. I timed it and output that time.

Then I decided to change it so that the forfind and whilefind functions were used multiple times (in this case 10000 times). However, the for loop find still came up with better performance than the while find. Can anyone explain this? Here is the code.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include<ctime>

template<class ln, class T>
ln whilefind(ln first, ln last, const T& val)
{
    while (first!=last && *first!=val) ++first;
    return first;
}

template<class ln, class T>
ln forfind(ln first, ln last, const T& val)
{
    for (ln p = first; p!=last; ++p)
        if(*p == val) return p;
    return last;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    vector<int>::iterator whiletest;
    vector<int>::iterator fortest;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n)
        numbers.push_back(n);

    clock_t while1 = clock();   // start
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        whiletest = whilefind(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), i);
    clock_t while2 = clock();   // stop

    clock_t for1 = clock(); // start
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        fortest = forfind(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), i);
    clock_t for2 = clock(); // stop

    cout << "While loop: " << double(while2-while1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds.\n";
    cout << "For loop: " << double(for2-for1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds.\n";
}
```

The while loop consistently reports taking around .78 seconds and the for loop reports .67 seconds.

Comment: try reversing the order - time the for loop first and then the while loop?

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion. If the first test pulls the necessary data into the cache, you'll see a big improvement in performance the second time you access that data. Another way to neutralize that effect would be to code the test as two separate processes.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?  If you're doing this in Visual Studio, are you compiling with microsoft's latest iterator checking stuff turned off?

Comment: There seems to be an error in forfind. 'if(*p = val) return p;' should be ==

Comment: Bug is fixed, but times are still shorter.

Comment: Firstly, turn all optimisations on. Secondly, test the different loops in separate executables, executed in random order.

Comment: Reversing the order changed the times around. Now it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Fun stuff is that on gcc reversing does _not_ change the times around: while's faster :-D

Comment: Using your suggestion Neil. I'll update in a minute

Comment: The fortest gave slower results this time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if(*p = val) return p;
```

That should be a `==`. So forfind will only go through the entire vector for the first value, 0, and return immediately for numbers 1-9999.

Comment: Gah you got it! But the for loop still outputs shorter times.

Comment: ahh, you're faster, collect the rep :)

Comment: @trikker: turn compiler optimisations on.  For example, in gcc v4.3.2, -O2 level yields while/for .04/.06, -O0 level yields .72/.66.  Not only it starts working 10 times faster (and you're to use -O2 everywhere you use C++), but _while_ easilly outperforms the _for_ loop.